# Google Apps Script - How can I send an email WITH reply-to but MASKING the sender address?

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, gmail, google-forms

I have a form that I've added a script to so that whenever a form submission comes through, an email is sent.  As I'm the form and script owner, all the emails come from my personal email.  This is fine and all, but best case scenario would be for the emails to show that they come from the submitter of the form response.  I don't think this is something that Google Apps Script can do right now, so I have it set up to capture the submitter's email address and put it in the "reply-to" field.

This works great, but everyone still thinks the emails are coming from me.  Is there a way I can mask the sender email address?  If I set "no-reply" to true, then the reply-to won't work.  Is there anything I can utilize to mask my email address that I'm not seeing?

```
function buildEmailOptions(responses) {
  let options = {
    replyTo: responses.respondent,
    cc: EMAILS_TO_CC + ", " + responses.respondent
  };
  return options;
}
```

Comment: Any thought on creating a separate email address to run your script from?

Comment: I was thinking about that.  I'll see if I can have my organization do that for me.

Comment: Alternatively, this may or may not help: https://simplelogin.io/blog/email-alias-vs-plus-sign/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Google Apps Script does not have that feature yet. You may use the following workarounds to address your issues:

## Workarounds

**1. Create Email Aliases Using Google Admin Console**

If you have an admin role in your organization's Google Workspace, then you can add email aliases to your account. You can refer to this article: [Give a user an alternate "email alias" address](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33327). You can contact your Google Workspace admin if you do not have an admin role assigned to your account.

**2. Create Another Account**

For users with @gmail accounts, option number 1 is not possible. Instead, you can create/add another account and link it to your current @gmail account. Just follow this article: [Send emails from a different address or alias](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370).